# How does this author solve commutation relation of Hamiltonian and a function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, commutator

In [this book](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198705413.001.0001/acprof-9780198705413)

> Modern Theory of Thermoelectricity by Veljko Zlatić and René Monnier

the author gives the following commutation relation in Eq $(11.11)$. I want to understand how they do it.

---

The Hamiltonian of a system is represented as $\hat{H}=\sum_i \hat{h}_i$ with $\hat{h}_i = \frac{\mathbf{\hat{p}}_i^2}{2m}$. The commutation relation they calculate is
$$
i \psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
$$
here $\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)$ and $f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)$ are any functions. They solve this commutation relation as given in following steps
$$
i \psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
=i\frac{\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)}{2m}\sum_{\alpha={x,y,z}}
\left[(p_i^\alpha)^2,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
\tag{1}
$$

$$
i \psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
=i\frac{\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)}{2m}\sum_{\alpha={x,y,z}}
\left\{ \left[p_i^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] p_i^\alpha + 
p_i^\alpha \left[p_i^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] \right\}
\tag{2}
$$

use $\mathbf{\hat{p}}_i=-i\nabla_i$ (please note that one $i$ represents imaginary number and $\hbar=1$)

$$
\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
=\frac{\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)}{2m}\sum_{\alpha={x,y,z}}
\left\{ \left[\nabla_i^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] p_i^\alpha + 
p_i^\alpha \left[\nabla_i^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] \right\}
\tag{3}
$$

$$
\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
=-\frac{\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)}{2m}\sum_{\alpha={x,y,z}}
\left\{ \left[\nabla^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] p_i^\alpha + 
p_i^\alpha \left[\nabla^\alpha,f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right] \right\}
\tag{4}
$$

$$
\psi (\mathbf{r}_i)\left[\hat{h}_i, f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)\right]
=-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla \cdot
\left\{ \psi (\mathbf{r}_i) \left[ f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i) \mathbf{\hat{p}}_i + \mathbf{\hat{p}}_i f(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)  \right]\right\}
\tag{5}
$$

I understand the first $3$ steps given above. I want to know how to reach to Eq $(4)$ and $(5)$ above?

Comment: For (4) apply the commutator $[\partial_a, f(x)]$ to a wave function.

Comment: @lcv thank you for the comment. Can you please elaborate more? How can I get to Eq (4) by using commutator $[\partial_a,f(x)]$. I believe it is $=\partial_a f(x) - i\hat{p}/\hbar$. In the book, they change from $\nabla_i$ to bare $\nabla$, which is believe is $\nabla_r$

Comment: Your commutator is off, check the algebra. You should also specify what you mean with $\mathbf{r}$ without subscript.